# Color only the row in table and not all the row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to color my table rows. To do this Im using :

```
Range("Table2[MyColumn]")(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 154, 265)
```

But this does color the whole row (even outside the table). See above.

[image]

How to color the row of a table ?

Comment: Do you expect the results to be a single column all the time? or will it sometimes have more than 1 column that you want highlighted?

Comment: @braX It will have more than one column

Comment: @braX I've edited my post so the example isn't missleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Address the list object correctly not with `Range("Table2[MyColumn]")` and it will work:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListRows(i).Range.Interior.Color = RGB(0,154,265)
```

I recommend: [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

The difference is that `Range.EntireRow` will address the entire row of the sheet but `ListRows` only the range of the listobject/table.

Comment: Damn thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You specifically mention to colour the entire row:

```
Range("Table2[MyColumn]")(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0,154,265)
```

Just drop the `EntireRow` part and only that one column will be coloured:

```
Range("Table2[MyColumn]")(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 154, 265)
```

**Edit after comment**

What about intersecting? (Not tested)

```
R1 = Range("Table2[MyColumn]")(i).EntireRow
R2 = Range("Table2[MyColumn]")

Application.Intersect(R1, R2).Interior.Color = ...
```

R1 is the entire row, which even gets outside of the table.
R2 is the entire table.
The intersection is that one row, bounded by the boundaries of the table.

Comment: Thanks Dominique, but this does Higghlight only One cell in each row..

Comment: I've Edited my post with a better example

Comment: @Dorian: You've edited your post with a better example, I've edited my post with a better answer (at least I hope) :-)

Comment: I will try yours to, but i think that listrows is the easiest way ! thank you

Comment: Even if you decide not to use it, you have learnt about the `Application.Intersect` function, so it's useful after all :-)